Creating a sidebar
I want to create sidebar which on pressing the hamburger menu translates to right from the left side and the page makes space for it. I've created something very close to what I want but I am having trouble with animation


const btnToggleSideBar = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle-sidebar")
const sideBar = document.querySelector(".side-bar");
const containerBefore = document.querySelector(".before");

btnToggleSideBar.onclick = (e) => {
  containerBefore.classList.toggle("hide");
  sideBar.classList.toggle("hidden");
};
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cont-outer {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 550px;
}

.side-bar {
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 1000ms ease;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 75% 0 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.side-bar.hidden {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.cont-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/* this is here to just push the main content to the right so that the sidebar doesn't cover the main page*/
.before {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #a3a3a3;
  transition: flex-grow 1000ms ease;
}

/* let main page to take entire space when side bar is moved to the left */
.before.hide {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.main-page {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 3;
}
<button class="btn-toggle-sidebar">toggle sidebar</button>
<div class="cont-outer">
  <div class="side-bar">
    <h4>list of items</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>apples</li>
      <li>oranges</li>
      <li>pineapples</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="cont-inner">
    <div class="before"></div>
    <div class="main-page"></div>
  </div>
</div>



When you hide the sidebar during animation you can see the .before div. Which I don't want to happen. The .before is shrinking slower than the sidebar is moving to the left even though both the sidebar and .before div have the same animation-timing and animation-style

It's unclear... so, you want .cont-inner to resize its contents dynamically when the menu opens? Don't you hate it that the eventual texts and images of that element will wrap all over the container during such an animation? (that's considered a bad UI/UX)

I am trying to replicate sidebar from this website https://app.todoist.com/auth/signup. You will have to sign up in order to use the app.

I've achieved it using margin-left but I still want to figure is there a way for me to achieve this using transform: translateX. Here is the codepen for my solution
https://codepen.io/vatsalraj-chauhan/pen/gOJbKYz

No, transform: translateX() will only move the element it is applied to, not the surrounding elements. However, you can achieve a similar effect by using margin-left as you did in your codepen.

I've done it here in the code snippet using transform: translateX() but the only problem is that there is speed difference between how fast main page covers the entire page on sidebar close and sidebar moving to left. You will see the grey background on it while the sidebar is closing.

@vatsalchauhan I copied everything from your original post into the codepen, set the flex-grow to 0 in the .before css section, and set the background-color to transparent. Is that what you're looking for?

No. I want the main page to shrink when sidebar is open and grow when sidebar is closed. I am very close to achieving this using translateX I just can't figure out why the timing is off in the animation of sidebar and .before element.
